# DISM Can Mount Image but Can't Apply It

Tags: wds, imaging, windows-pe, dism, wim

I am using DISM to capture a Windows image. I have successfully captured an image from the reference computer after running `sysprep` and booting from Windows PE. This was done manually using the `DISM /Capture-Image` command with the `verify` argument.

It created an image which I want to deploy through WDS.

Before we even get there, I try to deploy the image manually to test that it works using the `DISM /Deploy-Image` command. If I do this then it fails with `error 13`.

The thing is that if I copy this image file to my laptop locally, I am able to mount it successfully to an empty directory and browse the files.

Can anyone help me get the image to apply?

Comment: Looks like this can happen when dism runs out of scratch space.  Have you tried using the /ScratchDir option to explicitly select which disk the scratch directory is on?  It needs to be sufficiently large, IIRC then typically the best choice is the same disk you are deploying the image to.

Comment: Same error unfortunately. I have created a scratch directory on the volume where the image file exists. I have ran the command as "dism /apply-image /scratchdir:D:\scratch /imagefile:D:\<imagefilename>.wim /index:1 /applydir:W:\

Comment: I have also since tried installing all the updates available onto the image and re-imaging.

Comment: This is Windows 10 1809, are there any known issues as I was able to successfully image from a wim created of a Windows 10 1803 image. Both have been created in the same fashion. The 1809 image was created as a fresh install of this version of Windows, not an inplace upgrade.

Comment: Now trying a 1903 image and getting the same error. Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue was to do with the version of the ADK used to generate the Windows PE boot USB. I skipped 1809 and moved to 1903.

I encountered the same issue on 1903 when I was using a PE generated from a lower version. I downloaded the ADK and PE add-in for 1903, recreated my bootstick and it then worked. I would say that this is the same issue for 1809 as well, but I haven't tested it on that version.